# Configurações de envio de formulário

Tags: mysql, html5, formulário, phpmyadmin

Bom galera, o que acontece... criei um formulário em php pra inserir em meu projeto, ocorre que, sempre dá algum erro ao enviar, e as vezes que consegui enviar não fez o envio de todos os dados mas apenas da "textarea". então depois de muito tentar, resolvi excluir tudo do mysql e da raiz do cpanel.
Por favor quem puder ajudar agradeço muito.
"preciso do passo a passo de quais arquivos devo criar, onde inserir e quais editar"

o código do formulário é esse:

```html
<form action="inserir.php" id="form1" method="post" name="form1">
<?php
import_request_variables("gP");
?>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
 <title>J &amp; S Solu&ccedil;&otilde;es Financeiras</title>
<h1 style="text-align: center;">Preencha o formul&aacute;rio abaixo que entraremos em contato com voc&ecirc; em at&eacute; 1 hora</h1>

<center>
<h3 style="text-align: center;">Em hor&aacute;rio comercial</h3>
</center>

<p></p>


<p></p>
        <!-- DADOS PESSOAIS-->
<fieldset><legend>Dados Pessoais (Obrigat&oacute;rio)</legend>

<table cellspacing="10">
 <tbody>
  <tr>
   <td><label for="nome">Nome: </label></td>
   <td align="left"><input name="nome" required="" type="text" /></td>
   <td><label for="sobrenome">Sobrenome: </label></td>
   <td align="left"><input name="sobrenome" required="" type="text" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td><label>Nascimento: </label></td>
   <td align="left"><input maxlength="2" name="dia" required="" size="2" type="text" /> <input maxlength="2" name="mes" required="" size="2" type="text" /> <input maxlength="4" name="ano" required="" size="4" type="text" /></td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
</fieldset>
<!-- RESPONDA -->

<fieldset><legend>Responda (Obrigat&oacute;rio)</legend>

<table cellspacing="10">
 <tbody>
  <tr>
   <td><label for="Eu Sou">Eu Sou:</label></td>
   <td align="left"><select name="Eu Sou"><option disabled="disabled" selected="selected" value="0">Selecionar...</option><option value="all">CPF</option><option value="all">CNPJ</option> </select></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td><label for="Eu Quero">Eu Quero:</label></td>
   <td align="left"><select multiple="true" name="Eu Quero"><option selected="selected" value="0">Selecionar...</option><option value="all">Fazer Um Empr&eacute;stimo</option><option value="all">Pagar Contas</option><option value="all">Me Tornar Um Correspondente</option></select></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td><label for="Melhor forma de Contato">Melhor Forma de Contato:</label></td>
   <td align="left"><select multiple="true" name="Melhor Forma de Contato"><option selected="selected" value="0">Selecionar...</option><option value="all">Liga&ccedil;&atilde;o</option><option value="all">WhatsApp</option><option value="all">E-mail</option></select></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td><label for="Preferência De Contato">Prefer&ecirc;ncia De Contato:</label></td>
   <td align="left"><select multiple="true" name="Preferência De Contato"><option selected="selected" value="0">Selecionar...</option><option value="all">Manh&atilde;</option><option value="all">Tarde</option><option value="all">Imediato</option></select></td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
</fieldset>
<br />
<!-- DADOS DE CONTATO-->
<fieldset><legend>Dados de Contato (Obrigat&oacute;rio)</legend>

<table cellspacing="10">
 <tbody>
  <tr>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td><label>Telefone: </label></td>
   <td align="left"><input maxlength="2" name="DDD" size="1" type="all" />-<input maxlength="8" name="TELEFONE" size="10" type="text" /></td>
   <td><label>WhatsApp: </label></td>
   <td align="left"><input maxlength="2" name="DDD" size="1" type="all" />-<input maxlength="9" name="WhatsApp" size="10" type="text" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td><label>E-mail: </label></td>
   <td align="left"><input name="email" size="25" type="email" /></td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
</fieldset>
<br />
<!-- CAIXA DE TEXTO-->
<fieldset><legend>Caixa De Texto (Opcional)</legend>

<table cellspacing="10">
</table>

<center>Escreva o que desejar:
<table>
 <tbody>
  <tr>
   <td align="left"><textarea cols="100" id="comentarios" name="comentarios" rows="10" size="20">  
</textarea></td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
</center>
</fieldset>
<!-- ENDEREÇO -->

<fieldset><legend>Dados de Endere&ccedil;o (Opcional)</legend>

<table cellspacing="10">
 <tbody>
  <tr>
   <td><label for="rua">Rua:</label></td>
   <td align="left"><input name="rua" type="text" /></td>
   <td><label for="numero">Numero:</label></td>
   <td align="left"><input name="numero" size="4" type="text" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td><label for="bairro">Bairro: </label></td>
   <td align="left"><input name="bairro" type="text" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td><label for="estado">Estado:</label></td>
   <td align="left"><select name="estado"><option value="ac">Acre</option><option value="al">Alagoas</option><option value="am">Amazonas</option><option value="ap">Amap&aacute;</option><option value="ba">Bahia</option><option value="ce">Cear&aacute;</option><option value="df">Distrito Federal</option><option value="es">Esp&iacute;rito Santo</option><option value="go">Goi&aacute;s</option><option value="ma">Maranh&atilde;o</option><option value="mt">Mato Grosso</option><option value="ms">Mato Grosso do Sul</option><option value="mg">Minas Gerais</option><option value="pa">Par&aacute;</option><option value="pb">Para&iacute;ba</option><option value="pr">Paran&aacute;</option><option value="pe">Pernambuco</option><option value="pi">Piau&iacute;</option><option value="rj">Rio de Janeiro</option><option value="rn">Rio Grande do Norte</option><option value="ro">Rond&ocirc;nia</option><option value="rs">Rio Grande do Sul</option><option value="rr">Roraima</option><option value="sc">Santa Catarina</option><option value="se">Sergipe</option><option value="sp">S&atilde;o Paulo</option><option value="to">Tocantins</option> </select></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td><label for="cidade">Cidade: </label></td>
   <td align="left"><input name="cidade" type="text" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td><label for="cep">CEP: </label></td>
   <td align="left"><input maxlength="5" name="cep" size="5" type="text" /> - <input maxlength="3" name="cep2" size="3" type="text" /></td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
</fieldset>
<br />
<input type="submit" /> <input type="reset" value="Limpar" />
</form>
<!--?
</php>
```

Comment: Igor, dá uma lida no texto da pergunta, essa parte acho que faltou algo: *"não fez o envio de todos os dados mas apenas da . então depois"*

Comment: Desculpe-me... sim. Enviou apenas o da <text-area>

Comment: Você pode clicar no link "editar" abaixo da sua pergunta [ou aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/315759/edit) para editar e corrigir. Coloca entre crases  para ficar assim: `<textarea>`

Comment: Ok, feito. Desculpem-me a ignorância, ainda estou aprendendo a linguagem, e nada melhor do que obter ajuda com quem entende. :D

Comment: Imagina Igor, estamos aqui pra ajudar, e quanto mais você dominar as ferramentas do site melhor :)

Answer (score 0):

Galera, editei o `inserir.php`, agora reporta este erro:

```
Atenção : mysqli_query () espera pelo menos 2 parametros, 1 dado em /home/silvahip/public_html/inserir.php on line 30
Erro ao enviar formulario Tentar novamente
```

```html
<?php
//conecta ao servidor e ao banco de dados
   $servidor='localhost';
   $banco='silvahip_formulario';
   $usuario='silvahip_contato';
   $senha='MINHA SENHA';
   $conexao=mysqli_connect($servidor,$usuario,$senha);
   if(!($conexao)){
      echo "Conexao Falhada"; exit;
   }
//Recebe valores por posts
$Nome = $_POST['in_Nome'];
$Sobrenome = $_POST['in_Sobrenome'];
$Nascimento = $_POST['in_Nascimento'];
$Eu_Sou = $_POST['in_Eu_Sou'];
$Eu_Quero = $_POST['in_Eu_Quero'];
$Melhor_Forma_de_Contato = $_POST['in_Melhor_Forma_de_Contato'];
$Preferência_De_Contato = $_POST['in_Preferência_De_Contato'];
$Telefone = $_POST['in_Telefone'];
$WhatsApp = $_POST['in_WhatsApp'];
$Email = $_POST['in_E-mail'];
$Rua = $_POST['in_Rua'];
$Numero = $_POST['in_Numero'];
$Bairro = $_POST['in_Bairro'];
$Cidade = $_POST['in_Cidade'];
$Estado = $_POST['in_Estado'];
$CEP = $_POST['in_CEP'];

//Comando sql para inserir dados à tabela
   ESSA É A LINHA 30 **$inserir = mysqli_query("INSERT INTO `Formulario` 
(Nome,Sobrenome,Nascimento,Eu_Sou,
Eu_Quero,Melhor_Forma_de_Contato,Preferência_De_Contato,
Telefone,WhatsApp,E-mail,Rua,Numero,Bairro,Cidade,Estado,CEP) 
VALUES('$nome', '$email', '$empresa', '$Nome', 
'$Sobrenome', '$Nascimento', '$Eu_Sou', '$Eu_Quero', 
'$Melhor_Forma_de_Contato', '$Preferencia_De_Contato', 
'$Telefone', '$WhatsApp', '$Email', '$Rua', '$Numero', 
'$Bairro', '$Cidade', '$Estado', '$CEP')");**

//Retorna se deu certo ou não
if($inserir){
 echo "Formulário Enviado Com Sucesso.<br />";
 echo "<a href='form.php'>Voltar ao formulário</a>";
 
}else{
 echo "Erro ao enviar formulário";
 echo "<a href='form.php'>Tentar novamente</a>";
}

//fecha banco de dados
mysqli_close($conexao);
?>
```

Comment: Galera consegui arrumar tudo ok, obrigado a todos pela atenção.